# how to set setAllowFileAccess as false in webview_flutter: ^4.2.0

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

how to set `setAllowFileAccess` as `false` in [webview_flutter: ^4.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/versions/4.2.0) need to restrict file storage access from web view flutter

I can't able to setAllowFileAccess as false in Flutter

I am facing a security vulnerabilities issue.